# Android Webview Handling Orientation Not Working

Tags: android, android-webview

Im using webview and I want to stop reloading the page when orientation changes.

I have the following in my activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ){
    ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView)).saveState(outState);
}
```

And in my layout, I have:

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:visibility="gone" >
```

But the above code didn't work. Im testing it in Android 2.3.3.

Comment: r u want to rotate that activity which have this webview?

Comment: its fine as long as the page is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to your activity which was used by this Layout in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".UserProfileActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

User screensize for newly version orientation might not be supported in some version need to use screensize for configChanges

Comment: remove screensize it will used for higher version like 11 or 14

Comment: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize|
 keyboardHidden').

Comment: I already have it :android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: it works... android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" should be attribute of activity.