# android:webView handling orientation changes

Tags: android, webview, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I want to prevent webview reload the page everytime when orientation is changed.

I've followed following tutorial:

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change

but it calls `onCreate()` method eveytime and fetches the page agin and again.

DisplayResult.java :

```
public class DisplayResult extends AppCompatActivity
{
protected FrameLayout webViewPlaceholder;


protected WebView webView;
protected Uri url;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_result);
    url = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Url"));
    initUI();
    Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this ,"Oncreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


protected void initUI()
{
    webViewPlaceholder =(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder);
    if(webView==null)
    {

        //webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView = new WebView(this);
        // webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        //webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(0);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl(url.toString());

    }
    webViewPlaceholder.addView(webView);
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    MaterialDialog m ;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {

        m=new MaterialDialog.Builder(DisplayResult.this)
                .title("Fetching Result")
                .content("Please wait...")
                .progress(true,0)

                .show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        m.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    webView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    if(webView==null)
    {
        webViewPlaceholder.removeView(webView);
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_result);
    url = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Url"));
    initUI();
}

}
```

and my layout file :

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/webViewPlaceholder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've also added in manifest file :

```
<activity
        android:name=".DisplayResult"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/display"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

Still it's not working. can anyone help me with solution :

I've also tried :

[Android Webview Handling Orientation Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762436/android-webview-handling-orientation-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
if(webView==null)
{
    webViewPlaceholder.removeView(webView);
}
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
setContentView(R.layout.display_result);
url = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Url"));
initUI();
}
```

Replace this with

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: You were reloading your webView onConfigurationChanged();

Comment: thanks for the Answer @AnkitKumar It helped a Lot... I thought that its not possible in our web-view But finally its working

Answer (score 3):

You haven't added the `screenSize` to the `configChanges`.

From the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):

> Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (`onDestroy()` is called, followed by `onCreate()`). The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration.

And:

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must declare `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize`. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

With that in mind, to prevent `onCreate()` from being called every time you change orientation, you would have to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the AndroidManifest.